# Typescript, Express, Mocha & Chai Error while testing

Tags: typescript, express, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I made my first server using express in typescript and it perfectly works

```
import app from './Server'

const server = app.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on standard port 80...");
});

export default server;
```

Now I try testing the routes stored in app:

```
import express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    res.status(200).send("SUCCESS");
});

export default app;
```

Using this test:

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

import server from '../src';

describe("LogAPI", () => {

    describe('Base express tests', () => {
        it("Should return 'SUCCESS' if GET /", async () => {
            return chai.request(server).get("/").then(res => {
                chai.expect(res.body).to.equal("SUCCESS");
            })
        });

        it("Should return status-code 200 by calling GET /", async () => {
            return chai.request(server).get("/").then(res => {
                chai.expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
            })
        });

    });
});
```

But even while running the server itself works, staring the test with

```
mocha --require ts-node/register ./../test/**/*.ts
```

throws me this error:

> /Users/.../NotificationService/src/Server/index.js:5
>   var app = express_1.default();
>                             ^
>   TypeError: express_1.default is not a function
>      at Object. (/Users/.../NotificationService/src/Server/inde> x.js:5:28)

I am using es6 target and commonjs module.
How can I properly test my server?

**Update 1**
I now fiddled a bit and it turned out that deleting the `default()` method from the compiled code resolved something.

Now, I get

> /Users/.../NotificationService/test/node_modules/@types/chai-http/index.d.ts:13
>   import * as request from 'superagent';
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

**Update 2**
My ts-config.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "outDir": "./../out“,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true   
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was to not use seperate package.json and tsconfig.json files. Thanks to deerawan, I now use

```
- tsconfig.json
- package.json
- src/
    - index.ts
- test/
    - test.ts
```

which resolves the issue!

Answer (score 3):

The error related to express is because express doesn't use default export, so the correct way is

```
// src.js
import * as express from 'express'
```

Don't forget to install type definitions so Typescript can compile it smoothly such as

```
npm install @types/express --save-dev
npm install @types/body-parser --save-dev
npm install @types/chai-http --save-dev
```

**Updated:**
I tried it locally with this `tsconfig.json`

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "types": [
        "node",
        "mocha",
        "express"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": [
        "es2015"       
      ],
      ...
  },
}
```

Using default export has caveat as described in 
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to do so from the beginning, but changing my my imports result in
`> error TS2497: Module '"/Users/.../NotificationService/test/node_modules/@types/chai-http/index"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.`

Comment: And using that import for express result in `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof e' has no compatible call signatures.
4 const app = express();
`

Comment: my bad, `chai-http` apparently can't be used with `import`. I tried it locally. I'm really curious with your express. I tried to reproduce it but I couldn't. May you posted your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I updated my question to include it. I also may upload the whole project excluding node_modules if you want.

Comment: @CodingVampyre Thank you. Try to remove your `esModuleInterop` from `tsconfig.json`. Using this setting doesn't allow you to use syntax `import * as ... from ...`

Comment: I think were getting somewhere. Now, `import * as express from 'express';` works, compiling does too, but npm test now throws

`/.../NotificationService/test/node_modules/@types/body-parser/index.d.ts:14
import { NextHandleFunction } from 'connect';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: @CodingVampyre that's good. What is your typescript version? and what does `npm test` contain?

Comment: Typescript has version 3.0.3, npm test runs

`mocha --require ts-node/register ./../test/**/*.ts` from src folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180505/discussion-between-deerawan-and-coding-vampyre).

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting a default import from `express`, but the module uses an export assignment.  Either replace `import express from 'express';` with `import express = require('express');` or set the `esModuleInterop` compiler option to `true` in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I did both, but the error remains and nothing in the behaviour changes. Running the server still works fine, but testing still results in above error.